# renaming (specific) column names in one liner in the construction of a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

`bar` is the requested output with the colnames as would be desired. Any way to do this in the one liner construction of `foo`, without using a second statement, i.e. rename `rn` and `V1` to `c` and `d` respectively in the construction?

Please note that the `list("s1" = 1, "s2" = 2)` has to stay as it is.

`bar` is the desired output:

```
   a   b   c  d
1: abc bcd s1 1
2: abc bcd s2 2
```

`foo` to mimick `bar`

```
   a   b   rn  V1
1: abc bcd s1  1
2: abc bcd s2  2
```

MWE script:

```
library(data.table)
bar <- data.table(a = "abc", b = "bcd", c = c("s1", "s2"), d = 1:2)
print("bar:")
print(bar)
foo <- data.table(a = "abc", b = "bcd",
                  data.matrix(list("s1" = 1,
                                   "s2" = 2)), keep.rownames = T)
# colnames(foo) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")  # without using a second statement like this
print("foo:")
print(foo)
```

PS: A workaround I did was to define a `reformat` function as follows for example

```
reformat <- function(dt) {
  colnames(dt) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
  return(dt)
}
foo <- reformat(data.table(a = "abc", b = "bcd",
                           data.matrix(list("s1" = 1,
                                            "s2" = 2)), keep.rownames = T))
print(foo)
```

but wandering if there is any way to do it without the need of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data.table` already has a function to rename columns without copying the `data.table`.

Are you loking for something like this?

```
setnames(foo <- data.table(a = "abc", b = "bcd", 
                           data.matrix(list("s1" = 1, "s2" = 2)), 
                           keep.rownames = TRUE),
         c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
print(foo)
     a   b  c d
1: abc bcd s1 1
2: abc bcd s2 2
```

Answer (score 4):

Am I missing something?

```
setnames(foo, old = c("c", "d"), new = c("rn", "V1"))
```